# Why does my variable takes this much space in Memory Usage?

Tags: php, session-variables

I have a huge Session variable and would like to know why it takes so much space in memory ?

Note: I am aware we should not be storing this much Data in the SESSION variable.

Here is the result of my tests

```
session_start();
memory_get_usage(); //returns: 627 000 (about 0.62MB)

$_SESSION['my_huge_var'] = array(THE ARRAY...) // This is a three dimensional array

strlen(serialize($_SESSION['my_huge_var'])) // returns: 8 804 969 (about 8.8MB)

memory_get_usage(); //returns 164 439 952 (about 164MB !!!!)

unset($_SESSION['my_huge_var']);

memory_get_usage(); //returns: 627 000 (about 0.62MB)
```

Comment: Maybe because it's huge?

Comment: [How big are PHP arrays](http://nikic.github.io/2011/12/12/How-big-are-PHP-arrays-really-Hint-BIG.html)

Comment: Could you share a sample of your data, I've got a horrible feeling you're assigning a lot of objects/arrays(and thus initialising a ton of hash maps taking up a load of memory just in case you ever start using it).

Comment: Stop storing huge volumes of data in session.... it should never be necessary

Comment: as far as I know, php is extremely inefficient when it comes about memory handling.

Comment: @Sergio - you're wrong, PHP is extremely efficient when it comes to memory handling, and does it all for you completely transparently; but it has high memory usage.... there is a big difference

Comment: @MarkBaker Thanks for the link, it really helped! We are getting rid of this three dimensional array and it won't be stored in a SESSION variable anymore. I simply wanted to understand why it was so big; we already knew it was bad practice to do something like that.